# How to highlight every occurrence in Lucene 4.4?

Tags: lucene, information-retrieval

I have a very special corpus, each document is actually a short paragraph.

What I intend to do is to highlight every occurrence of a search term, not just a fragment like the Highlighter class does.

For example:

> Search 'apple', the result should be something like this:
>
> I eat an **apple** everyday because an **apple** a day keeps the doctor away.
>
> instead of
>
> ...eat **apple** everyday because...
>   ...an **apple** a day keeps...

Answer (score 0):

The [Fragmenter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Fragmenter.html) handles how the text is split up (or fragmented).  The [NullFragmenter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/NullFragmenter.html) is intended for cases in which you don't want any fragmentation, simply like:

```
highlighter.setTextFragmenter(new NullFragmenter());
```